# Open Multiple Instances of taskmanager

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, task-manager

Is there a way to open multiple taskmanagers in Windows 10? I trie this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61970/Running-multiple-instances-of-Task-Manager but it doesn't work. So I tried to write a .bat file to start multiple instances but it still doesn't work

```
@echo off

start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
```

Comment: Several users (including me) report, that when the system is under load (as in: very laggy, not just normal 100% cpu usage) and the user starts Task Manager several times (for example with ctrl-shift-esc) then it can happen that two (or maybe even more) Task Manager windows appear. This is of course not a reliable way to start multiple instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  But if you use [*Process Explorer*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from [Sysinternals.com](http://sysinternals.com/) instead of Task Manager then you can run multiple instances if you so wish.

[image: Screenshot of menu]

Sysinternals is now part of Microsoft's [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals).  The *Process Explorer* application provides enhanced capability over and above that found in *Task Manager*.

Comment: This is a good alternative to better monitor my cpu, memory, hdd